# Java Virtual Machine and mutually blocking theads

Tags: java, jvm

Does the Java Virtual Machine specification require that it have a mechanism that determines whether threads are mutually blocked?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it does not require this. It's hard to prove a negative, though.

Comment: The [Java Virtual Machine specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/) is online.

Comment: [This section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.10) is probably of some importance of the topic as it hints at what's *not* required.

Comment: “[The Java programming language neither prevents nor requires detection of deadlock conditions.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1:~:text=The%20Java%20programming%20language%20neither%20prevents%20nor%20requires%20detection%20of%20deadlock%20conditions.)”